# Trouble consuming Gradle plugin project with 3rd party maven repository

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am attempting to create a Gradle plugin that is set up like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    // note the custom maven repo
    maven { url = "https://maven.gentics.com/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi(),
            localGroovy(),
            "com.gentics.mesh:mesh-rest-client:${MESH_VER}" 
    testImplementation gradleTestKit()
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:${SPOCK_VER}") {
        exclude module : 'groovy-all'
    }
}
// the rest...
```

However if I try to consume this plugin in another project with `includeBuild "./gradle-mesh"` in the `settings.gradle`, I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'functionalTest'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.gentics.mesh:mesh-rest-client:1.7.1.
    Searched in the following locations:
    - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/gentics/mesh/mesh-rest-client/1.7.1/mesh-rest-client-1.7.1.pom
    If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
    Required by:
        project : > project :gradle-mesh
```

However, I am able to execute the `functionalTest` in the actual plugin tests without issue. Getting rid of that line in the `settings.gradle` and renaming the folder to `buildSrc` works as well.

Is there a way to configure the `buildscript` dependencies from within the plugin entry point? I tried the following, but it didn't make any difference.

```
class GradleMeshPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.buildscript.repositories.configure {
            mavenLocal()
            jcenter()
            maven { url = "https://maven.gentics.com/maven2" }
        }
        
        // dependency is referenced here...
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to go about this?

Full Project: https://github.com/wawebio/gradle-mesh

System:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.8 (Ubuntu 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-47-generic amd64
```

**Update**
I was also able to get it to work by adding the following in the consuming project's `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url = "https://maven.gentics.com/maven2" }
    }
}

rootProject.name = 'website'

includeBuild "./gradle-mesh"
```

Is there a way to do this from within the plugin application itself?

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify your mvn package‌‌‌​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌‌‌​​​‌​‌‌​‌‌‌‌ differently, which is the first one.

```
<configuring-project>
```

Comment: You're not really explaining why this solves the problem. Can you add a little bit more information about where, why, and how your solution works?